# Cloud Firestore не выдает сразу данные при повторном запросе

Tags: android, firestore

Подскажите, пожалуйста, это ограничение бета-версии новой базы данных от Firebase или глюк такой? При повторном запросе данных у базы, ответ не выдается какое-то время, потом выдается. При одинарном запросе - все получается, но при повторном ответ выдается примерно через минуту - две. Код стандартный:

```
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()){
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Map<String, Object> snap = document.getData();
                some...
            }}}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Это ошибка самого Cloud Firestore, т.к. находится в бета режиме, то и работает соответственно.